# R - remove dates five days before and after a given list of dates

Tags: r, dataframe, date

Let's suppose I have the following date `data.frame` [df_date](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/6dyy0jva24xoz57c70w9i/dates.csv?rlkey=2k92py65scz1bzkdbdt1qrx3w&dl=0) that contains a given number of dates in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Based on dates of `df_date` I need to remove all the corresponding dates before and after 5 days, starting from the older date up to the most recent date.

For example, the first three rows of `df_date` are: 1866-01-10, 1866-01-11 and 1866-01-21. Here the resulting output would be: 1866-01-10 and 1866-01-21.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure I understand you need but check if this works for you using dplyr:
df_date$remove <- sapply(df_date$date, function(x) (df_date %>% filter(date>x-5 & date<x) %>% nrow()))
Then execute this to filter the result: df_date %>% filter(!remove)

Comment: You'll likely get better, faster help if you edit your question to include reproducible data (including the data that you have and the desired data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a vector of dates dt

```
start_date <-as.Date("1866-01-10")
end_date <- as.Date("1866-02-10")
dt <- seq(start_date,end_date, by = 1)
```

and you subsample from this 10 dates and store it in dt1 (which corresponds to your date column in your data frame)

```
dt1 <- sort(sample(dt, 10))
dt1
# [1] "1866-01-14" "1866-01-15" "1866-01-18" "1866-01-23" "1866-01-24" "1866-01-25" "1866-01-29" "1866-01-30" "1866-02-04" "1866-02-09"
```

you can do something like that to only get dates, which are minimally 5 days apart:

```
for(l in 5:1){
  dt1 <- dt1[c(rep(999,l),diff(dt1, lag = l)) > 5]
}

dt1
# [1] "1866-01-14" "1866-01-23" "1866-02-04"
```

Be careful, this solution assumes that every date only appears once in your date vector. Otherwise, you have to increase l to the number of maximum duplicates + 5.

It may also be possible to solve your problem in the tidyverse using the functions lag or lead.

Answer (score 0):

## base R

```r
subset(df_date, abs(date - date[1]) <= 5 | abs(date - date[length(date)]) <= 5)
#           date
# 1   1866-01-10
# 2   1866-01-11
# 421 1873-12-24
# 422 1873-12-29
```

or

```r
df_date[rowSums(abs(outer(df_date$date, range(df_date$date), `-`)) <= 5) > 0,,drop=FALSE]
#           date
# 1   1866-01-10
# 2   1866-01-11
# 421 1873-12-24
# 422 1873-12-29
```

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
filter(df_date, abs(date - first(date)) <= 5 | abs(date - last(date)) <= 5)
#         date
# 1 1866-01-10
# 2 1866-01-11
# 3 1873-12-24
# 4 1873-12-29
```

---

Data

```r
df_date <- read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/6dyy0jva24xoz57c70w9i/dates.csv?rlkey=2k92py65scz1bzkdbdt1qrx3w&dl=1") |>
  transform(date = as.Date(date))
nrow(df_date)
# [1] 422
head(df_date)
#         date
# 1 1866-01-10
# 2 1866-01-11
# 3 1866-01-21
# 4 1866-02-08
# 5 1866-02-21
# 6 1866-02-26
```